# Flex Builder: generate html wrapper parameters

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

how can I set embed parameters for html wrapper using Flex Builder ?

For example, I would like to generate the code that allows fullscreen, directly from Flex Builder, so I can debug properly.

Where can I find these parameters ?

thanks

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
            id="${application}" width="${width}" height="${height}"
            codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
            <param name="movie" value="${swf}.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="${bgcolor}" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
            <embed src="${swf}.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="${bgcolor}"
                width="${width}" height="${height}" name="${application}" align="middle"
                play="true"
                loop="false"
                quality="high"
                allowfullscreen="true"
                allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
                type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
            </embed>
    </object>






  /* fullScreen */
    public function fullScreen():void {
        Application.application.stage.displayState = (!isFull) ? StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN : StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
        if (isFull) {   

             isFull=false;
        } else {    
            //Application.application.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;   
            isFull=true;
        }

        debugF.text = isFull.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to modify your html wrapper by hand, because only several things (like flash player version, deep linking) can be configured from the FB interface. Or you can modify the template files. You can find them in .metadata.plugins\com.adobe.flexbuilder.project\html-templates\

Comment: the template files, this is exactly what I needed. However, I dunno why fullscreen doesn't work. Is this html wrapper allowing fullscreen ? (I wrote it in the question)

Comment: Yes it allows by default. You should have something like Application.application.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN in a handler which should invoked by a user generated event (click for example). If it does not work just post the code.

Comment: I have it, but it doesn't work.. this is my code. (see above). thanks

Comment: It's strange, it should be ok. Can you isolate the issue? Have a mini flex app with just a button calling fullScreen?

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy.

Each project contains "html-template" folder with index.template.html file.
Change this file according to your needs.